# Rails Mapping relational DB Ids into an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapreduce

I have the following models

```
venues(id, name, ....)
categories(id, name, ....)
categories_venues(id, venue_id, category_id)
```

I want to create an array of the categories one venue has been associated with. The relation is of HABTM kind.

**What i have tried?**

```
@venue = Venue.friendly.find(params[:id])
categories = @venue.categories.map { |x| x.id }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `@venue.categories.pluck(:id)`.

This will create `SELECT` query for only `id` field

Comment: you'll get array of id's, why you need mapping?

Answer (score 2):

you could use:

```
@venue.category_ids
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i guess `has_many through` will help you out.for example:-
```

---

```
  #####in user.rb

    ##association for getting all users and thier groups /vice-versa
     has_many :user_groups, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :groups, :through => :user_groups
 ---------------------------------------------------   
     ####in group.rb

     has_many :user_groups, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :users, :through => :user_groups
-----------------------------------------------------------     
    #####in user_group.rb

     belongs_to :group
     belongs_to :user
-------------------------------------------------------------    
    ###and we have the necessary migration(its easy... :))..
    so now


    @user=User.find(1)
    all_groups_for_user=@user.groups.where("name=?","Alumni")
    all_names_of_groups_for_user=@user.groups.map(&:name)
```

if you use `scopes/class methods` than...you can get more data with `joins/include`

Comment: lot of things completed based on HABTM. next version i will take ur suggestion :D